# Check Syntax with parentheses in the variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a form with a field. The Format they need to enter is as follows. 
10.222.92.160(asxvlc558-ipsn),10.222.92.161(asxvlc559-ipsn),10.222.92.162(asxvlc560-ipsn)

I dont care too much about whats between the parens but I do care about the IP format where the Parens are and the comma delimitation.

Can someone provide a snippet of code.  Ive tried to use the RegExp to do it but cant get the match correct.

Here is the form line

```
<textarea name="ro_access" onchange='validatehost(this.value)'>
10.10.10.10(somehost01-ipsn),10.10.10.11(somehost02-ipsn)</textarea></td>
```

Here was my stab at the JS part. Not much of a JS guy so dont laugh to much.

```
function validatehost( value ) {
    var ipRE = new RegExp('\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\(*\),');
        var r = ipRE.test(value);
if (r >= 0) {
    alert("Hostnames are not in the Right Format. Use:ip(hostname),");
         document.NFSNew.ro_access.focus();
         return false;
}
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression syntax is wrong, you're matching `(` "zero or more" times by quantifying it with the `*` quantifier. Instead, you can use the `.` and make it a non-greedy match between.

If the format can be repeating, I would place it inside of a group and use anchors.

```
var ipRE = /^\s*(?:\d+\.){3}\d+\(.*?\)(?:,(?:\d+\.){3}\d+\(.*?\))*\s*$/
```

**Note:** It's much easier to use a regex literal here instead of a RegExp object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example:

```js
function validatehost (value) {
  var ipRE = /^\s*(?:\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\(.*?\)(?:,(?!\s*$)|\s*$))+$/;
  alert(ipRE.test(value));
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text" cols="40">
10.10.10.10(somehost01-ipsn),10.10.10.11(somehost02-ipsn)
</textarea>
<button onclick="validatehost(document.getElementById('text').value)">Validate</button>
```

The main error was there:

```
new RegExp('\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\(*\),');
```

You're passing a string to the `RegExp` constructor, but your backslashes are lost: type `"\d"` in the JS console, you'll see it ends up as `"d"`. You either have to double the backslashes or to use a regex literal like I did there.

I also changed the regex. It should match your needs.

Comment: Note: It will match a trailing comma. Just letting you know.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
function validateHost(hosts) {
    return /^\s*(?:(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\)(?:,\d|$))+\s*$/.test(hosts);
}
```

for the hostname part it will accept this characters `a-zA-Z0-9-` (all lowercase, all uppercase and all digits), if you don't care you can put `.+?` which implies anything but at least 1 character. For the ip part will require max 3 digits min 1 per number and 4 numbers. It's not fool proof because someone could input a number higher that 255 but should be pretty solid. If you want perfect match and don't want any spaces around the string remove `\s*`.

Comment: Note: Your regex does not seem to match.

Comment: it matches but doesn't allow any spaces at the beginning https://regex101.com/r/lL4vV2/1, changed accordingly.